# Audio pops: Disable power save for snd_usb_audio?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, pulseaudio, power-management, alsa

TL;DR: How do I disable power save features for snd_usb_audio alsa-driver?

I have a Focusrite Scarlett 18i20 external soundcard. During boot as well as whenever no sounds have been played for a short while there are small pops, as if the device is turned on / off. Happens for instance when starting a YouTube video. I suspect this is the power save feature as I've read people have similar problems with the integrated cards.

Using pacmd to list-sinks I've determined the card is using alsa-driver name "snd_usb_audio". Where I go from there to disable power save, however, is beyond me as I'm new to this. Haven't been able to dig up a good thread either, so I'm asking here.

Comment: Had the same issue on 20.04.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe turn it off like this:

```
# echo 0 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

More information [here](https://major.io/2019/03/04/stop-audio-pops-on-intel-hd-audio/).

Comment: in that case, the proper module would be snd_usb_audio

Comment: Thanks! Asus Zenbook notebook with Ubuntu 20.04 here.